# .net framework (WPF) dependencies of references

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a .NET framework WPF project that references a .net standard library that I wrote. This library references `io.ports.dll`

I found that there is a problem with .net framework referencing .net standard projects and that it would not copy the `io.ports.dll` to the output folder. The solution here was to add the dependency to my WPF project also which solved the problem.

However I noticed that the two projects reference the `io.ports.dll` from different locations.

The WPF project references from

> project location\packages\System.IO.Ports.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.IO.Ports.dll

The .net standard library io.ports.dll location is

> C:\users\.nuget\packages\system.io.ports\4.5.0

The DLLs have different sizes, although they are the same version.

The problem appears when I use advanced installer to create a .msi. 
It gets very confused and tries to copy both DLLs and in the end my .net standard library tries to read the wrong DLL.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel answered (now deleted) that it was due to my GUI project using the old packages.json. This solved the original problem. Another problem was that the io.ports dll has a dependency on Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll which I also had to add to the GUI project.